# OpenXml Edit text in the header of a word file

Tags: asp.net, vb.net, openxml

I'm using Open XML and I should change the text in the header of a word file. To change a specific paragraph in the document I have used the following code:

```
Dim body = wdDoc.MainDocumentPart.Document.Body
            Dim paras = body.Elements(Of DocumentFormat.OpenXml.Wordprocessing.Paragraph)()
            Dim header = body.Elements(Of DocumentFormat.OpenXml.Wordprocessing.Header)()


            For Each para In paras
                For Each run In para.Elements(Of DocumentFormat.OpenXml.Wordprocessing.Run)()
                    For Each testo In run.Elements(Of DocumentFormat.OpenXml.Wordprocessing.Text)()
                        If (testo.Text.Contains("<$doc_description$>")) Then
                            testo.Text = testo.Text.Replace("<$doc_description$>", "replaced-text")
                        End If
                    Next
                Next
            Next
```

thanks in advance!

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You can use the following code to replace a tag in the header of a word document:

```
Using wdDoc = WordprocessingDocument.Open("header.docx", True)

  For Each headerPart In wdDoc.MainDocumentPart.HeaderParts
    For Each currentParagraph In headerPart.RootElement.Descendants(Of DocumentFormat.OpenXml.Wordprocessing.Paragraph)()
      For Each currentRun In currentParagraph.Descendants(Of DocumentFormat.OpenXml.Wordprocessing.Run)()
        For Each currentText In currentRun.Descendants(Of DocumentFormat.OpenXml.Wordprocessing.Text)()

          If (currentText.Text.Contains("$doc-description$")) Then
            Console.WriteLine("found")
            currentText.Text = currentText.Text.Replace("$doc-description$", "replaced-text")
          End If

        Next
      Next
    Next
  Next

End Using
```

First, enumerate all `HeaderParts` of the word document. Then search for all `Text` elements
containing the tag to replace. Then replace the tag with your text.

Please note that you should use a tag without `<>` and `_` characters. If your
tag contains these characters then word splits the text among multiple `Text` elements.

If you want to change the text in a table (or in any other element) just search
for all `Text` elements:

```
Using wdDoc = WordprocessingDocument.Open("header.docx", True)

  For Each headerPart In wdDoc.MainDocumentPart.HeaderParts
    For Each currentText In headerPart.RootElement.Descendants(Of DocumentFormat.OpenXml.Wordprocessing.Text)()

      If (currentText.Text.Contains("$doc-description$")) Then
        Console.WriteLine("found")
        currentText.Text = currentText.Text.Replace("$doc-description$", "replaced-text")
      End If

    Next
  Next

End Using
```

Comment: @andrea85: I've updated my answer to show how to replace text contained in a table. Please accept/upvote my answer if it helped you by clicking on the hollow arrow to the left of the answer.

Answer (score 16):

Ported to C# from Hans answer!

```
 //Gets all the headers
 foreach (var headerPart in doc.MainDocumentPart.HeaderParts)
 {
      //Gets the text in headers
      foreach(var currentText in headerPart.RootElement.Descendants<DocumentFormat.OpenXml.Wordprocessing.Text>())
      {
          currentText.Text = currentText.Text.Replace("[Thanks]", "Thanks");
      }
 }
```

Comment: I am applying section break for unique header for particular pages. 
How to change header for the particular pages?

Answer (score 0):

thanks for the reply actually works :)
I also tried with the following code:

```
    For Each headref In mainDoc.Descendants(Of DocumentFormat.OpenXml.Wordprocessing.HeaderReference)()
    headerRelationshipId = headref.Id.Value
    headerType = headref.Type.Value.ToString()
    Dim header01 As DocumentFormat.OpenXml.Wordprocessing.Header = DirectCast(wdDoc.MainDocumentPart.GetPartById(headerRelationshipId), HeaderPart).Header
    Dim headerText As New StringBuilder()

    For Each text00 As DocumentFormat.OpenXml.Wordprocessing.Text In header01.Descendants(Of DocumentFormat.OpenXml.Wordprocessing.Text)()
        If (text00.Text.Contains("")) Then
            text00.Text = text00.Text.Replace("", "replaced-text")
        End If
    Next
Next
```

But if I wanted to change the text in a table (instead of a paragraph)?